# Compare multinomial logistic regressions with multiple dependent variables

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, model-comparison

My dataset looks like this:

```
    agevote gender      comcat1      comcat2      comcat3      comcat4      comcat5
1         0      1         High         High         High         High         High
2         1      0 Distributive Distributive       Public       Public       Public
3         0      0         High         High         High Distributive Distributive
4         0      0       Public       Public       Public       Public       Public
5         1      1         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
6         0      1       Public       Public         High       Public       Public
7         0      0         High         High Distributive Distributive Distributive
8         0      0       Public       Public Distributive Distributive Distributive
9         0      1         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
10        1      1       Public       Public         High         High         High
```

In this dataset, each row is a single person. `comcat1` through `comcat5` capture the assignments of a person to one of three different groups at five different time points (yearly). `agevote` and `gender` are my independent variables.
I use multinomial regression to analyse how they affect assignment to groups. Given that the group assignment changes over time for individual observations, I would like to know if my independent variables contribute differently over time.

Therefore, I run five regression models:

```
mod1 <- multinom(comcat1 ~ gender + agevote, data = data)
mod2 <- multinom(comcat2 ~ gender + agevote, data = data)
mod3 <- multinom(comcat3 ~ gender + agevote, data = data)
mod4 <- multinom(comcat4 ~ gender + agevote, data = data)
mod5 <- multinom(comcat5 ~ gender + agevote, data = data)
```

And these are the corresponding results using the full dataset (N varies slightly due to missings):

```
=========================================================================================
                           Model 1     Model 2      Model 3      Model 4      Model 5    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Distributive: (Intercept)     0.09        0.12        -0.06         0.19         0.12    
                             (0.21)      (0.20)       (0.20)       (0.21)       (0.21)   
Distributive: gender         -0.84 **    -0.91 ***    -0.68 *      -0.57        -0.57    
                             (0.35)      (0.34)       (0.36)       (0.35)       (0.35)   
Distributive: agevote        -0.00       -0.08        -2.16 ***    -3.13 ***    -2.32 ***
                             (0.45)      (0.44)       (0.76)       (1.04)       (0.76)   
High: (Intercept)            -0.20       -0.15        -0.26        -0.12        -0.23    
                             (0.22)      (0.22)       (0.21)       (0.22)       (0.22)   
High: gender                 -0.26       -0.58 *      -0.02        -0.05         0.05    
                             (0.34)      (0.35)       (0.32)       (0.33)       (0.33)   
High: agevote                -0.32       -0.49        -0.88 *      -0.88 *      -0.75 *  
                             (0.50)      (0.52)       (0.47)       (0.45)       (0.45)   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AIC                         497.31      499.11       499.24       499.95       495.31    
BIC                         517.83      519.72       520.00       520.71       515.96    
Log Likelihood             -242.66     -243.56      -243.62      -243.97      -241.65    
Deviance                    485.31      487.11       487.24       487.95       483.31    
Num. obs.                   226         229          235          235          231       
K                             3           3            3            3            3       
=========================================================================================
```

*My question now is: can I compare statistical significance levels and/or coefficients between the models?*

For example, can I argue that something that happened between time points 2 and 3 (model 2 and model 3) accounts for agevote becoming a significant predictor with a positive effect on assignment to the distributive group over the public goods group?

I appreciate any help you can give and say sorry for any missing information in advance. I'm happy to add anything you think relevant as soon as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently my "hello everyone" went missing. Hello everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you do this for a simpler regression, such as a linear model rather than multinomial logistic?

Comment: Thank you, Dave! Frankly, I don't have a clue. Could you help me out here?

Comment: It's hard for me to follow what you have written. It would be better if you include a sample of your data clearly indicating what's your response variable and what are the independent variables and then ask your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Amin! I updated my entry and hope it is clearer now. If not, I'll happily improve it further.